# Nginx PHP API CORS

Tags: ajax, nginx, cors

I'm developing the SPA with VueJS which should operate with PHP API/Nginx on the remote domain. Of course I've faced the CORS problem.

Here is the recent Nginx config file:

```
 location / {

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,some_my_tokens';

            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '1728000';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,some_my_tokens';
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' '0';
                return 204;
            }

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        }
```

I'm still getting Errors "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://remote_host:8080' is therefore not allowed access.".

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below code in your index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); // cache for 1 day

}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: PHP hacks do work. Any options to solve it with nginx config only?

Comment: @dayan, you can do it via nginx.conf, check my answer

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when our backend was sending an error response, for example in PHP `header('HTTP', ERROR_CODE)`, was resulting in CORS headers missing from response.

Adding the `always` parameter to these CORS headers fixed the issue:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
```

As the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) states about `add_header` directive

> Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0).

and docs says about `always` parameter

> If the always parameter is specified (1.7.5), the header field will be added regardless of the response code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's saying `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` is because.....

wait for it....

no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You have this directive in your location block:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

But then you have an `if` condition for `OPTIONS` requests, and within that level you don't have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

From [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header)

> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are
>   inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no
>   add_header directives defined on the current level.

So your `OPTIONS` preflight will be missing the header.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using `more_set_headers` on nginx.conf instead of `add_header`, for example:

```
   location / {

            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,some_my_tokens';

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '1728000';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,some_my_tokens';
            more_set_headers 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
            more_set_headers 'Content-Length' '0';
            return 204;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }
```

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 by doing:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras